# Hazelcast c++ client, map and TTL

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have an entry (k1, v1) in map with ttl say 60 secs.

If I do map.set(k1, v2), the ttl is not impacted, i.e. the entry will get removed after 60 seconds. 
However, if I do map.put(k1, v2), the ttl will seize to exist, i.e. entry will not be removed after 60 seconds.

Is this understanding correct? I guess it this way, but could not find it clearly mentioned in documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. There was a bug for map.put when using configured ttl time. I just submitted the PR for the fix here with the additional tests: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-cpp-client/pull/164

We mistakenly sent 0 instead of -1 for the ttl. -1 means to use the configured ttl. This was correct for set API already, the problem was only with the put API.

Thanks for reporting this.

Answer (score 1):

No, both put and set operation have same under lying implementation except that set operation does not return the oldValue.
You can take a look at the `PutOperation` & `SetOperation` classes, both are extending `BasePutOperation`.
Unless you are setting the ttl for every put/set operation, eviction should be based on the latest ttl value of entry.